# Trouble installing Ubuntu 13.10 on UEFI disk

Tags: installation, boot, uefi

Gurus

I am trying to install Ubuntu 13.10 amd64 on a Lenovo M91P thinkcenter. But every post install boot ends up with 1962: No OS found. I want to keep just Ubuntu as the only OS on the host (previously running Win XP SP3)

This is what I have done so far:

1. Intially I tried installing the server OS (since thats what I wanted). Previously the station was running Win XP proff SP3. Saw the issue for the first time.
2. Did some googling to come across Ubuntu UEFI help articles https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI - Tried both trial and error and install in EFI mode using Ubuntu Gnome 13.10. No good

Basically, I have tried to install from "Try Ubuntu" option of live DVD also, both retaining and erasing the existing partitions, but no improvement.

Below is the boot repair summary link

[BootRepair summary run from Live DVD of the current state](http://paste.ubuntu.com/6555314/)

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Best

Soumik

Comment: I ran dmesg | grep EFI from Live session and the following is the output  
[    0.000000] efi: EFI v2.00 by American Megatrends  [    3.617179] fb0: EFI VGA frame buffer device
[    4.007326] EFI Variables Facility v0.08 2004-May-17
[    5.644428] fb: conflicting fb hw usage inteldrmfb vs EFI VGA - removing generic driver

Comment: It looks to me like you need to partition your disk again so that you have a root directory. at the moment you've got no bootloader so the system can't boot. Check out threads on how to partition your drive for ubuntu only and try doing that.

Comment: The computer *does* have boot loader files -- they're on `/dev/sda1`. The computer has an EFI, not a traditional BIOS, so the computer booted in EFI mode and the Ubuntu installer set up an EFI-mode boot loader on `/dev/sda1`. This is perfectly normal on an EFI-based computer; however, some EFIs are buggy and there are still bugs on the Linux side, too, so it doesn't always work. There's also a root (`/`) filesystem defined, but it's inside the LVM setup. Again, this is *not* an error.

Answer (score 0):

I have three main suggestions:

- Upgrade your firmware. You may have a buggy EFI that's causing problems. Sometimes upgrading will solve the problem; however, upgrading alone may not be sufficient -- you may need to jump through some extra hoops, like re-installing or doing the next two steps.
- Boot an emergency system *in EFI mode* and run the [Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) tool. This can fix many such problems. You may need to use the advanced menu and select the option to back up the Windows boot loader file and copy GRUB in its place. (I realize you don't have Windows, but some EFIs are badly broken and look for its boot loader.)
- Try my [rEFInd boot manager.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/getting.html) You can try the USB flash drive or CD-R version risk-free. If it works, install the Debian-package version in Ubuntu. If that works, you're done; but if not, boot into Linux using the CD-R or USB flash drive and then try using the [alternative naming options.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/installing.html#naming)

You can try these things in any order that you like.

Answer (score 0):

I went back to legacy boot mode, set up the MBR GRUB and Ubuntu is running fine. Good for me, I didn't require dual boot, going by what you say.

I did try Boot Repair (only the recommended fix), but it was no good.